# What's the idiomatic way to use io.ReaderAt with the io/fs abstraction?

Tags: go

I'm writing something that will read ranges of data from files at specific offsets from different types of filesystems.

I want to be as idiomatic as possible, and use Go's `io/fs` abstraction.

`io.FS` is pretty minimalistic, and offers just one way to access files:

`Open(name string) (File, error)`

The `File` interface, in turn, has a basic `Read` method, and offers no way to seek to/read at an offset.

The docs say, "A file may implement io.ReaderAt or io.Seeker as optimizations." I'm not really sure what to do with that.

Are they expecting something like:

```golang
f, _ := myfs.Open(filename)
if ff, ok := f.(io.ReaderAt); ok {
  //
  // Main code that will read at offset.
  //
  ff.ReadAt(...)
} else {
  panic(" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ")
}
```

It seems like the best I can really do is define my own `FS` like:

```golang
type File interface {
  fs.File
  io.ReaderAt
}

type FS interface {
  Open(name string) (File, error)
}
```

Is this the intent, or is there a more idiomatic approach I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, they are expecting code as in the first snippet of code in the quesstion.

Comment: Defining your own `FS` interface that returns your own `File` interface won't do you much good, since existing implementations won't be compatible with it (they return `fs.File`s, not `yourpackage.File`s).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I was a bit annoyed at how clunky it is to have to do these type checks all over the place, but I suppose it could be thought of as just as clunky to have to implement a bunch of "not implemented" methods for filesystems that don't support some version of seek/readAt semantics (which is... very few of them afaik).